# jQuery prevent image from dragging too far

Tags: jquery, draggable

We have an image inside a div set to `overflow: hidden`. I have it set so that the image is draggable.

How can we get it so if you try to drag the image too far it stops at the edge?

Right now it snaps back into place which would work but is not exactly what we are looking for.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/Ksd6n/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI draggable comes with a method for constraining movement.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

It looks something like this:

```
$( "#draggable4" ).draggable({ containment: "#demo-frame" });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work too well if the inner image is bigger than the parent.

Comment: Right, I tried containment set to .imageBox and it totally broke the ability to drag smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ , you can influence the dragging either by creating a dragger helper, or by setting the inner $(this).data('draggable').offset.click. ...
Don't know if this is the best solution, but tested it by adding this inside draggable (after yPos is filled):

```
    if(yPos > 0)           
        $(this).data('draggable').offset.click.top += yPos;
```

That did indeed reset the position when trying to drag down (albeit a bit jerky). Should work for the other directions as well. (and something tells me that jquery possesses better properties to accomplish this)
Example that prevents dragging right and down: http://jsfiddle.net/Ksd6n/6/